# Add AD FS login to existing ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, iis, adfs, wif

I'm working on a web-facing ASP.NET site and have been tasked with adding an AD FS sign in to a subfolder of the site (eg. https://website.com/secret/test.aspx). The main site (https://website.com) must not require any log in.

We want to use passive WIF to our AD FS SAML 2.0/WS-Federation endpoint (am I saying that right) that then redirects back to https://website.com/secret/test.aspx.

I'm able to redirect through the STS with some additions to the root Web.conf:

```
<!-- Start WIF authentication additions in <configuration> -->
<configSections>
  <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" />
  <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" />
</configSections>
<location path="FederationMetadata">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<!-- End WIF authentication additions -->
```

...

```
<!-- Start WIF authentication additions in <system.web> -->
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="None" />
<!-- End WIF authentication additions -->
```

...

```
<!-- Start WIF authentication additions in <system.webServer> -->
<modules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<!-- End WIF authentication additions -->
```

...

```
<!-- Start WIF authentication additions after <system.identityModel> -->
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <audienceUris>
      <add value="https://website.com/secret/test.aspx" />
    </audienceUris>
    <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX">
      <trustedIssuers>
        <add thumbprint="XXX" name="XXX Relying Party Trust" />
      </trustedIssuers>
    </issuerNameRegistry>
    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.identityModel.services>
  <federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://fs.website.com/adfs/ls" realm="https://website.com/secret/test.aspx" reply="https://website.com/secret/test.aspx" requireHttps="true" />
  </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
<!-- End WIF authentication additions -->
```

But this forces authorization for the entire website, not just the /secret/ subfolder, and I'm having way more difficulty trying to figure this out than I think I should. Is this the right approach? Should I be looking into a solution that's entirely code-based?

The website is not MVC.

Thanks for any direction you can provide, even if it's just some more accurate terminology I should Google.

Software Versions:

Web Server - Windows Server 2016 v1607 b14393.2665 (IIS v10.0.14393.0)

AD FS Host - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "allow / deny" on folders via web.config, either at the root level or at the folder level.

e.g.

```
<location path="Folder">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="*"/> 
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

So in general allow users (as per metadata above) and deny access at a folder level.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I moved the authorization tag from the root system.web into the subfolder and it all worked..